# Can I use sudo for kill not root processes?

Tags: kill, sudo

Can I use sudo for kill only not root processes ?

Comment: `sudo kill` lets you send signals to any process.  (Although not all signals can be sent to the `init` process.)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo kill -n ID_of_process_to_signal`

Where n is a number from the list off `kill -l' (that is the letter l).
If none is specified then signal 15 TERM (software termination signal) will be used.

Note that this is the same as for normal usage of kill. Why ask specifically for kill run as root?